# How to detect if a located element is indeed on top and clickable using uiautomator2?

Tags: android, android-uiautomator, uiautomatorviewer

```
import uiautomator2
device = uiautomator2.connect()
elem = device(resourceId="com.someapp.droid.full:id/publisher_content_row",
            className="android.view.ViewGroup")
elem.click(5)
```

It is often clicking the bottom-bar or the top bar as the selected item might be hidden behind them occasionally.

Comment: You could make a XML file with device.dump_hierarchy() and then retrieve the element with uiautomator2 and compare it to the format of the XML file (first loaded nodes will be on top).

Answer (score 0):

Use the Barista library for UI tests, it is the easiest solution and makes everything easier. https://github.com/AdevintaSpain/Barista

With Barista, you can do it like this:

```
assertClickable("Hello world")
assertClickable(R.string.hello_world)
assertClickable(R.id.button)
```